# How i can automate a circuit using transistors instead switches?

Tags: transistors, switches, counter, microwave, automation

I'm recycling the counter circuit of a microwave, for use it as a stopwatch, that turns on automatically, and start the count per seconds immediately when turns on, the circuit have two buttons "switch count: the button that increase one second when press and release the button" and "switch mode: the button that switch of mode between clock or count, when are press and release".

[image: Example Updated]

the idea is replace the two switches by two transistors, first replace the "mode switch" that communicate the signal one time simulating one touch and release automatically(for change the mode from clock to counter) because default mode is clock when turns on the circuit, and the second replace the "count switch: the button that increase the 1 value from 00 min 00sec upto 12 min 00sec, when press and release, second per second (touch per touch)" with a transistor that simulates the touch and release second per second, multiple times until go to 12 min 00sec.

i've try soldering the two entries of the mode switch, but not works because it needs be released not only a touch, and it requires some ms of delay pressed, and i do that too with the count switch, and not works too, because it makes the count button count per ms not per seconds, and it fall in a loop 00min 00sec to 12min 00sec and it repeats ever...

i've read exist some transistors that can do this, but i don't know how to do it, i'm not expert, The signal ARE POSITIVE.

Comment: without knowing what sort of signals flow on those wires it's not practical to propose a circuit.

Comment: i've tested it some times i think is positive, i've use a multimeter to find it

Comment: question updated...

Comment: the signal reacts to 1.6v 20ma in both switches, don't have to make a circuit, if you want say what transistors can operate that actions, it helps much, for example the counter(a out voltage signal waiting one second between emitting the signal), and in the mode what transistor send a voltage signal one time when are turn on.

Comment: You should also find out how the switches are wired on the microwave's circuit board. A relay can be used as a "drop-in replacement" for a mechanical switch no matter how the switch is wired, but a transistor may have to be wired differently  depending on how the switch is wired. (If you don't want to figure it out and you are okay with an extra clicking noise, you might consider using relays)